# sed command with regexp

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I don't understand the result of this command using "sed".

Ex:

```
echo "Here is my website: https://mywebsite.blabla/files" | sed -e 's/.* //g'
```

Result:

```
https://mywebsit.blabla/files
```

Now I add a second "https":

```
echo "Here is my https website: https://mywebsite.blabla/files" | sed -e 's/.* //g'
```

And again the result with sed is the same.

As far as I understand, the `s/.* //g` means substitution of whatever matching any zero or more character(s) and a space with nothing (`//`), up to the end of the chain.
Obviously I'm missing something.

Any idea?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be the same? You're replacing everything until the last space. `https` has nothing to do with what you're matching.

Comment: Welcome to SO. `.* ` is greedy match it will match till last space in line, hence it is not stopping match before last `https`and till last space.

Comment: Try throwing your patterns in https://regex101.com/; it will explain exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

`sed -e 's/.* //g'` use `sed -e 's/<search>/<replace>/g'` function of sed.

In your example, the search pattern is `.*` it will match:

- `.` every character
- `*` 0 times or more
- until a space

Now the result seem logic: you will replace all but last "word" with nothing.